# Comparar valores de um mesmo campo em uma tabela

Tags: sql-server

Estou começando em SQL e apareceu um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho uma tabela em que estão registrados os pagamentos de vários clientes, cada cliente realizou 6 pagamentos. Eu preciso saber quantos clientes fizeram os 6 pagamentos sempre com o mesmo valor. Alguém pode me dar uma idéia de como posso contar isso?
[image: Um exemplo de como estão os dados]

Nesse caso o cliente 239 entraria para a contagem e o 43 não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você precisa contar os registros agrupando-os por **pessoa** e **valor**. Daí aplica uma cláusula ***HAVING*** para filtrar apenas os resultados da contagem iguais a 6.

```
SELECT cod_pessoa
  FROM pagamentos
 GROUP BY cod_pessoa, valor
HAVING COUNT(*) = 6
```

Lembrando que, se uma mesma pessoa efetuou 6 pagamentos de R$10 e mais outros 6 pagamentos de $20, por exemplo, ela aparecerá no resultado duas vezes.

Para evitar a duplicidade utilize o ***DISTINCT*** na sua *select*, assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cod_pessoa
  FROM pagamentos
 GROUP BY cod_pessoa, valor
HAVING COUNT(*) = 6
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Que bom amigo. Se a solução resolveu seu problema não esqueça de sinalizar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Feito, sou usuário novo ainda, agora sim sinalizado!

Comment: Sem problema amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Valor supor que a sua tabela seja pagamento a estrutura dela seja

```
create table Pagamentos(
       id int,
       cod_pessoa int,
       valor numeric(15,2)
)
```

Para você acessar quantas pessoas efetuaram 6 pagamentos segue a query

```
select cod_pessoa
  from pagamentos
 group by cod_pessoa
having count(*) = 6
```

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pela resposta, a estrutura da tabela é essa, mas na verdade eu queria, para cada cod_pessoa, comparar os valores e separar apenas os que tivessem pago o mesmo valor nas 6 parcelas.